# Grep regular expressions for single character

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a dictionary of words and I want to do a test to see if a generated words exists in the list so I'm using grep.  My problem is I cannot get grep to stop returning unwanted resposes.

For example.  I want to grep the word menu and return only the exact match so I used:

```
grep -iw menu words.dat
```

This returned both menu and menu's.  I've played around with regular expressions such as:

```
grep -ie '^menu.' words.dat
```

This returns everything starting with menu and any number of characters after it.  Again, if I use the same command with -w, I still get menu and menu's.

How can I restrict the grep command to do a wild card on one single character.

Comment: kindly post the sample Input and expected output in code tags.

Comment: Do you want to search for a word and return only the exact match, or do you want to use a wild card? Also, what "single character"?

Comment: not clear, but if you want to match whole line, see if your grep supports `-x` option... then `grep -ix 'men.'` will return only 4 character whole lines starting with `men`... without -x, it will be `grep -i '^men.$'`

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear and now re-reading it I can see my confusion.
I have the string, 'men', and I want to grep any occurrences of any four character words starting with 'men' from a file.
So should get menu but not menu's.
Does that help?
It would also appear my version of grep does not support -x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the meaning of the `-w` flag.  What you are apparently trying to do is

```
grep -x menu. words.dat
```

which will require the match to cover the entire line.

The normal behavior of `grep` is to return the entire matching line whenever the regular expression matches anywhere on the line.

The `-w` option says that the match must be isolated from other text by "non-word" characters.  The exact definition of "word" vs "non-word" may also depend on your locale, but the traditional C/POSIX semantics are that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` are "word" characters and anything else (aka `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` -- which includes, you might notice, apostrophe and dash) isn't.  So `grep -w menu` will match `menu's` because the text which matches the regex is adjacent to (nothing or) non-word characters.

The `-x` option is basically equivalent to wrapping the regex with `^` (beginning of line) and `$` (end of line) anchors.  So `grep -x menu` is a convenient equivalent to `grep '^menu$'`, i.e. match beginning of line, m, e, n, u, end of line.

For completeness, I'll also mention `-o` which says to only output the text which matched.  So `grep -o boo <<<'kaboom'` will print `boo` out of the matching line (and `grep -wo boo <<<'kaboom'` will print nothing because while a match is present, it is not adjacent to non-word characters, or nothing).

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear and now re-reading it I can see my confusion. I have the string, 'men', and I want to grep any occurrences of any four character words starting with 'men' from a file. So should get menu but not menu's. Does that help? It would also appear my version of grep does not support -x.

Comment: Then add the anchors like I suggested in the post.  You want the regex `^men.$` (and you need it to be in single quotes to protect it from the shell).

Answer (score 2):

With negative lookahead and lookbehind

```
grep -iP '(?<![\w\x27])menu(?![\w\x27])'  words.dat
```

I have used the ascii code of single quote `\x27` instead the actual character. 
Effectively you include `'` into the "word" for word boundary considerations.

---

```
$ cat words.dat
menu
MENU
notmenu
NOTMENU
menu's
$ grep -iP '(?<![\w\x27])menu(?![\w\x27])'  words.dat
menu
MENU
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I needed.  Or seems to work.

```
grep -ix '^men.\{2,2\}' words.dat
```

This returned any items starting with men and had a single character after it. In effect giving me any 4 letter word starting with men.

Thanks to those who responded.

Comment: This would give you any *5-character* word (unless you count characters very differently from the rest of us; "men" is 3 and then you allow 2 more).  Also the second `,2` is redundant here, and you don't need `^` together with `-x`.